# plt.pause causing a second window to pop-up

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using WCSsubplot and after a person clicks the window I want it to display text. But to get it to display I have to put in plt.pause() before closing the window. However, this pause function is causing a second window to pop-up after the user clicks the window and the text appears. How do I remove it?

Here is my code:

```
ax = plt.subplot(projection = wcs_cropped)

scatter = ax.scatter(object_ra, object_dec, transform=ax.get_transform('fk5'), s = circle_size, edgecolor='#40E842', facecolor='none')
ax.imshow(total_data.data, cmap = 'Greys', norm = norm1_w1)

#Display image until it is clicked to find the object
n = -1
while True:
      press = plt.waitforbuttonpress()
      text_max = len(text_list) - 1

      #Checks that it was a mouse click
      if press == False:
        n += 3

        #Finds which axes was clicked
        click_axes = str(location[n])
        click_axes = click_axes.split('WCSAxesSubplot', 2)[0]

        #Checks if the image was clicked
        if click_axes == '':
          shape_x, shape_y = total_data.shape[0], total_data.shape[1]
          ax.text(shape_x/20, shape_y/5, 'Your Click Has Been Successfully Recorded for 2MASS! \n              Please Wait for the Next Catalog to Load!', style='oblique', bbox={'facecolor': '#40E842', 'alpha': 1, 'pad': 10})
          plt.pause(0.1)
          plt.clf()
          plt.close('all')

          #Find the closest point to the location clicked to obtain W1, W2, W3, and W4 photometry
          coord = wcs_cropped.pixel_to_world_values(location[n-4],location[n-5])
          distance = []
          for i in range(len(object_ra)):
            distance.append(math.dist(coord, [object_ra[i], object_dec[i]]))

          list_location = distance.index(np.min(distance))
          ra_2mass, dec_2mass = object_ra[list_location], object_dec[list_location]
          j, j_e = j_list[list_location], j_list_e[list_location]
          h, h_e = h_list[list_location], h_list_e[list_location]
          ks, ks_e = ks_list[list_location], ks_list_e[list_location]
          return ra_2mass, dec_2mass, j, j_e, h, h_e, ks, ks_e, '2MASS All-Sky Point Source Catalog', text_list[text_max]
```

Comment: Please post an executable code sample - you may fill some arbitrary data just for making the code executable (don't forget to include the import statements). Maybe you have to call `plt.show()` somewhere.